# Series 2 Apple Watch Battery Drain in Absence of iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

Can anyone else confirm if their Series 2 Apple Watch battery drains faster when it's not connected to iPhone?  I leave my watch at home when I go to work, because my work poses too many threats for it, and it seems the battery dies faster in this situation.  I assume it's because the watch is looking for the phone.  Anyone else experience this?  Are there any settings to change to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, my Series 2 drains faster if it's not connected to iPhone. I put the watch in Airplane mode to save battery when it's not near the iPhone. It lasts much longer. You should try that.

Comment: Glad to hear it is not just me.  I'll try airplane mode.  Would be nice if Apple added an option in settings that would turn on and off automatic pairing of devices.  Something that, when turned off, would require a quick manual pair of the devices - a small inconvenience, but at the price of saving the battery, it would be useful.

Comment: In the absence of your iPhone, your WATCH relies on Wi-Fi to retrieve data, rather than Bluetooth LE. If applicable it would also power up its own GPS antenna rather than rely on the iPhone's. Both of these would cause increase battery drain without it having anything to do with pairing necessarily. Why not leave your watch on its charger if you're going to leave it at home?